# Rails - Active record querying with 350,000 records takes too much time

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, postgresql-9.1, psql

I am trying to plot a graph based on date and number of messages sent out on that particular. The query to get this count runs through three tables mentioned below.

Account table, Messages table, and Keyword table

The associations are like this.

- Keyword has_many Accounts.
- Account has_many Messages and belong_to Keyword
- Messages belongs_to Account

I need to check the number of messages sent out per day.

Here is the Query which I am using.

```
(@from_date.to_date..@to_date.to_date).map {|date|
Message.joins(:account).where("date(messages.created_at) = ? 
AND accounts.keyword_id = ?", date, keyword.id).count.to_f}.inspect
```

Please let me know any suggestions that can reduce the time to run this query.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do just like this:

```
keyword.messages.where(
    :created_at => [@from_date.to_date..@to_date.to_date]
).count
```

it will query like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM `messages`
WHERE `keyword_id` = [keyword.id] AND (`created_at` BETWEEN '[from_date]' AND '[to_date]')
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside Message model add this

```
def date
  self.created_at.strftime('"%d-%m-%Y')
end

 Message.joins(:account).where("date(messages.created_at) <= ?  AND date(messages.created_at) >= ? AND accounts.keyword_id = ?", @from_date.to_date,@to_date.to_date, keyword.id).group(:date).count
```

Try above can help you out